# OCaml Compilation Type Error, not the right expected type of the function

Tags: ocaml

New to OCaml Here.

Basically trying to compile a piece of code mostly with two functions, but I can't compile it with type error on line 9, column characters 26-27, saying:

"Error: This expression has type t but an expression was expected of type
         string""

Basically, the parse function called on line 8 is expecting type string, but I can't figure out why.

Type of the sexp argument:

```
type sexp = Atom of string | List of sexp list
```

code:

```
open Sexplib.Sexp

let rec parse_bindings bindings =
  match bindings with
    | [] -> []
    | first::rest ->
      match first with
        | List([Atom(name); e]) ->
          [(name, parse e)] @ (parse_bindings rest)

let rec parse sexp : expr =
  match sexp with
    | Atom(s) ->
      (* some code *)
    | List(sexps) ->
      match sexps with
        | (* some code *)
        | [Atom("let"); List(bindings_sexp); e2] ->
          let binding_expr = parse_bindings bindings in
            ELet(binding_expr, parse e2)
        | _ -> failwith "foo"
```

Comment: You should post a small self-contained example. This code doesn't compile because of `(* some code *)` and missing definitions. It's much easier to help if people can try your code themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The code as you give it won't compile because `parse` is referenced on line 9, but isn't defined until later.

To define two mutually recursive functions you need to use `let rec ... and ...`:

```
let rec f x = (* definition of f, which calls g *)
and g x = (* definition of g, which calls f *)
```

Since the later definition of `parse` isn't visible on line 9, the name must refer to some previous definition. Maybe there's a function named `parse` defined in the `Sexp` module. (This is one reason to use `open` carefully.)

Comment: Thanks! It works. One side question, how do I specify the parse used on line 9 to be a function from this file. In other languages, usually there is a namespace like thing to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: There's no simple way to refer to the current module. The idiomatic solution (IMHO) is remove `open Sexplib.Sexp`. If it's too onerous to use the full module name you can make a short name instead: `module S = Sexplib.Sexp`. Then you can use names of the form `S.Atom` etc.